# Inserting json data into a SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x

```py
import cursor as cursor
import requests
import pprint
import pyodbc

:
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=MY-PC-PC;'
                      'Database=test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


def read(conn):
     print("Read")
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute('select * FROM test.dbo.books')
     for row in cursor:
         print(f'row = {row}')
     print()


r = requests.get('https://5f97076911ab98001603b6d0.mockapi.io/api/v1/books')
#  pprint.pprint(r.json()) #to print all the data
#  pprint.pprint(r.json()[1]['author']) #to print user number 2 data
print(r.json()[1]['author'])
cursor = conn.cursor()
for i in range(50):
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.books (id, createdAt, title, author, imageUrl) "
                   "VALUES (r.json[i] ,r.json()[i]['createdAt'],r.json()[i]['title'], r.json()[i]['author'],r.json()[i]['imageUrl'] )")


conn.commit();
 read(conn);
    
read(conn)

cursor.close()
```

I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/MY-PC/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/py.py", line 40, in 
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.books (id, createdAt, title, author, imageUrl) "
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'i'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You are not using "i" or "r" as variables there, but as simple text. Try using a fstring, which would be putting an f before the "" and using {} to use your variables, as I do in this example:

```
name = "MyName"
print(f"Hello {name}")
```